# calling a void method from serverside using html hyperlink in design view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, serverside-javascript

Hi I have got a simple query , i m not able to call the method from html hyperlink tab , below is the code:

```
<a href="#" id="startUploadLink">Start Upload</a>

     $("#startUploadLink").click(function () {
         $('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').uploadifyUpload();
          //I want to call a method here which is on server side which is bindData()
           return false;
     });
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void bindData()
 { caravans.InsertImages() }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PageMethods](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109), and [jQuery's ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).